# Is it possible to send a thumbnail of an image with FCM?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging, base64

I just developing a communication application like Whatsapp and I just want to know can i compress and decode an image for thumbnail with BASE64 with size of 4Kb to send it via FCM to target phone ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know , you need to upload that first and then you can send that link using FCM and on the another side you need to fetch that image.

Comment: At first I did as you said and just a link of thumbnail and image is send via FCM and then in another side download them ... But I think I can do better with this new method that I ask

Comment: Then if you can store the image in byte[] array form and send it to another side and again try to show it. I haven't done something like this earlier so can't say that it will work or now.